# Add class to button based on button value

Tags: button, addclass

I am trying to add a class to a button based on the button value using the following code but no success:

```
<button type="button" value="Order Details" class="">Button</button>
```

and

```
$('input[type="button"][value="Order Details"]').addClass('red');
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You targeting an input element, but the element is a button element.

```
 $('button[value="Order Details"]').addClass('red');
```

Also possible to only target the value like this:

```
 $('[value="Order Details"]').addClass('red');
```